# ngFor isn't working on <tr> element of my angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I'm working on a demo CRUD project and I requested the sections from my component where I hard-coded employees data. I am not able to receive the data in table rows. I don't see what's making this not work.

**Component Html template (employees-list.component.html)**

```html
    <div class="container my-5">
      <h1 class="mb-5">Employees</h1>
    
      <table class="table" *ngIf="employees.length > 0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Department</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let emp from employees">
            <td>{{emp.id}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.email}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.salary}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.department}}</td>
    
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    
      <p *ngIf="employees.length <= 0">No employees found</p>
    </div>
```

**Component ts template (employees-list.component.ts)**

```js
    import { Employee } from './../../../models/employee.model';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-employees-list',
      templateUrl: './employees-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./employees-list.component.css']
    })
    export class EmployeesListComponent implements OnInit {
    
      employees: Employee[] = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'John Doe',
          email: 'john.doe@mail.com',
          phone: 1234567890,
          salary: 100000,
          department: 'IT'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Bob Builder',
          email: 'bob.build@mail.com',
          phone: 2345678901,
          salary: 200000,
          department: 'HR'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Phineas Ferb',
          email: 'phineas.ferb@mail.com',
          phone: 3456789012,
          salary: 300000,
          department: 'Scientist'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'Nobita Nobi',
          email: 'nobita.nobi@mail.com',
          phone: 4567890123,
          salary: 400000,
          department: 'Marketing'
        }
      ];
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
```

**App module file (app.module.ts)**

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { EmployeesListComponent } from './components/employees/employees-list/employees-list.component';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        EmployeesListComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Here below you can see that I am not able to get data in table rows

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, it should be [*ngFor with of](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf).

```
<tr *ngFor="let emp of employee">
  ...
</tr>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fschzx?file=src/app/employees-list/employees-list.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

You named your variable `employee` in the `.ts` file, but you are accessing it as `employees` in the template.

So, change your your `.ts` file like this:

```
employees: Employee[] = [...];
```

Also, you should use `of` instead of `from` in the template:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let emp of employees">
```

Comment: I changed it and it still isn't showing the data

Comment: Yeah, I now see you had another error with incorrect syntax. I see you already figured it out, but I updated my answer anyway.